# Can i send sensor data from arduino to cloud without sending it via PC

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to build a GPS tracker. I need to send the data from GPS sensor on the arduino uno board to cloud directly i.e. without sending it via PC or mobile.
Is it possible and if yes, HOW?

Comment: GSM module...? Or does that equate to "mobile" for you?

Comment: use an esp8266 and a router.

Comment: The best way of sending data straight to a cloud will be by laser.:)  You can use any method of networking that is applicable to your situation, ESP8266 is probably the best as @dandavis says, but also there is Ethernet.  If you allow yourself a receiving stations then blue tooth, IR and RF are also possibilities.

Comment: Another option is an Arduino board that has built-in wifi hosting, e.g. Arduino MKR1000 https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-mkr1000

Answer (score 1):

To connect to the cloud directly while the tracker is on the move, you'll need to use GSM & GPRS technology, ie. a SIM card to make a 3G/4G connection to the Internet. GSM gets you connected, GPRS does the Internet traffic. Using WiFi to connect to a router won't work since you'll soon get too far from the router.

I suggest initially investigating the SIM908 and SIM800L (there are others).

Here are 2 projects which both use the SIM908 (GSM, GPRS **AND** GPS):

[Geolocation Tracker (GPRS + GPS) with SIM908 over Arduino and Raspberry Pi](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/geolocation-tracker-gprs-gps-geoposition-sim908-arduino-raspberry-pi/)

[Where is my car? Realtime GPS+GPRS Tracking of Vehicles Using Arduino](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/projects/arduino-realtime-gps-gprs-vehicle-tracking)

The cheaper SIM800 is also popular GPRS/GSM module (no GPS capability, but you already have that?):

[QUICKSTART SIM800 (SIM800L) WITH ARDUINO](http://www.ayomaonline.com/programming/quickstart-sim800-sim800l-with-arduino/)

This technology is moving quickly, so you may find better options, for instance see:

[Difference between SIM908 vs SIM808 modules](http://www.raviyp.com/embedded/212-difference-between-sim908-vs-sim808-modules)

Hope this helps, 
Regards, Geoff

Answer (score 1):

Arduino UNO is a micro controller without any internet communication. In order to send data to the cloud, you need to have an internet connection (meaning TCP/IP stack).

In regards with your project, there are 2 major solutions:

1. Store all data locally on EEPROM (if not too much data because there is only 1KB on the Arduino Uno) or an external flash memory (there are some modules and libraries for this). When the Arduino is connected, you send over all the data to the cloud.
2. Send the data while data are collected.

In both case, you need an internet connection that could be managed by a wifi module or a GPRS module depending on your needs.

For the wifi module, the ESP8266 is a popular and cheap choice. You will find a lot of documentation on Google.

For the GSM/GPRS module, I suggest the SIM800L which is cheap and easy to use (there is a HTTP/S stack embedded on the module).

Comment: btw AI Thinkers - the creators of the esp8266, have developed a gsm board too, that might be worth taking a look at - https://www.iot-experiments.com/ai-thinker-a9-module-with-custom-firmware/

Answer (score 0):

Not with a UNO alone, the UNO obviously needs internet connection either via a LAN shield, a Wi-Fi unit (ESP8266) or a GSM unit.
Since you are GPS tracking then a GSM unit is most suited.

Particle Electron GPS receiver (Location plotted on Google Map)
https://www.brianmoreau.com/projects/particle-electron-gps-receiver/particle-electron-gps-receiver.php